# Retrieve Repeater items after drag and drop

Tags: asp.net, drag-and-drop, repeater

I have two repeaters that contain a collection of items.  On my page, the items can be dragged from one repeater to the other.  How can I access the items that are now in the repeater?  In the code behind, the repeater has the same values as when the page first loaded.  Is this even possible?

Both repeaters are in divs as below, if this helps.

```
<div class="container" style="height:400px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid #000000;" ondrop="drop(this, event)" ondragenter="return false" ondragover="return false">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="interfaceRepeater">
        <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="interfaceitem" style="width: 200px" id="<%# Eval("MAC") %>" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(this, event)">
                <b>Interface <%# Eval("ID") %></b><br />
                Client ID: <%# Eval("MAC") %><br />
                Client Type: <%# Eval("ClientType") %>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe that, since none of your controls in the `ItemTemplate` are server-side controls, they will not be restored on postback. I believe. Most likely, you will need a hidden textbox (with `runat=server`) that will maintain the changes so they can be passed back to the server during postback.

Comment: Tried that, but nothing gets updated on the server side.  Thanks for the thought though.  I'll just keep playing, or change how this works as I'm starting to think this just isn't possible.

Comment: The hidden textbox idea _will_ work, it's just that more code will need to be written in order to implement it. If this is still relevant and you would like me to provide you with some code showing how to do it, just let me know. I would need to see some more of your code so I could tailor the solution to your use case.

Comment: I ended up using javascript to loop through the items contained in my 'container' div to pull out the ID of items that are now there, then posted those back to the page on submit.  I would like to see the hidden textbox idea though as I am sure I, and others could find it useful.  Thanks.